# CSS navigation fade in / fade out on click animation does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need your help, I've checked all the documentation but I can't find the solution. I have a simple HTML navigation. In CSS, I have a fade in and out animation. The fade in works perfectly, but the fade out does not work. I've tried a million things, it just won't work.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const hamburgerMenu = document.getElementById("hamburger-menu");
  const mobileNav = document.querySelector(".mobile-nav");

  hamburgerMenu.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (mobileNav.classList.contains("open")) {
      mobileNav.classList.remove("open");
      mobileNav.classList.add("close");
    } else {
      mobileNav.classList.remove("close");
      mobileNav.classList.add("open");
    }
    const menuIcon = document.getElementById("menu-icon");
    menuIcon.src = mobileNav.classList.contains("open")
      ? "/media/cross_nav.svg"
      : "/media/hamburger_nav.svg";
  });
});
```

```css
  .mobile-nav {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--neutral-1000);
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  .mobile-nav.open {
    animation: slideDown 0.3s ease forwards;
  }

  .mobile-nav.close {
    animation: slideUp 0.3s ease forwards;
  }

  @keyframes slideDown {
    from {
      transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
    to {
      transform: translateY(0);
    }
  }

  @keyframes slideUp {
    from {
      transform: translateY(0);
    }
    to {
      transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
  }
```

```html
<header class="mobile">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="/media/yogism_logo_header.svg" alt="Logo" />
  </div>
  <nav class="mobile-nav">
    <div class="hamburger-menu" id="hamburger-menu">
      <img src="/media/hamburger_nav.svg" alt="Menu" id="menu-icon" />
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Testimonial</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

The class does toggle. When the page is just being loaded the first time, there is no class:

```
class="mobile-nav"
```

When I click it ones, it opens with the animation and becomes this:

```
class="mobile-nav open"
```

When I click it again, the navigation just dissapears without an animation, the html becomes this:

```
class="mobile-nav close"
```

When I then click it again, it opens again WITH the animation:

```
class="mobile-nav open"
```

Comment: Please note that other users may come across your question in the future, so references to the current time (Easter Sunday) are irrelevant. Also, due to timezones it isn't even Easter in some places in the world :)

Answer (score 0):

Initially there is no open or close and the style

```
.mobile-nav ul {
  transform: translateY(-200%);
}
```

in applied. When the style is either open or close the transition will play.

I moved the SVG to the CSS background -- I don't know if that will work for you?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const hamburgerMenu = document.getElementById("hamburger-menu");
  const mobileNav = document.querySelector(".mobile-nav");

  hamburgerMenu.addEventListener("click", function() {
    mobileNav.classList.toggle("open");
    if (mobileNav.classList.contains("open")) {
      mobileNav.classList.remove("close");
    }else{
      mobileNav.classList.add("close");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#hamburger-menu {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDEwMCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4KICA8cGF0aCBkPSJNIDUgMTUgaCA5MCBNIDUgNTAgaCA5MCBNIDUgODUgaCA5MCIgc3Ryb2tlPSJibGFjayIgc3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoPSIyMCIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.open #hamburger-menu {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDEwMCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4KICA8cGF0aCBkPSJNIDEwIDEwIEwgOTAgOTAgTSAxMCA5MCBMIDkwIDEwIiBzdHJva2U9ImJsYWNrIiBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9IjIwIiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4=');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.mobile-nav {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--neutral-1000);
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.mobile-nav ul {
  transform: translateY(-200%);
}

.mobile-nav.open ul {
  animation: slideDown 0.3s ease forwards;
}

.mobile-nav.close ul {
  animation: slideUp 0.3s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes slideDown {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-200%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes slideUp {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-200%);
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="mobile">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="/media/yogism_logo_header.svg" alt="Logo" />
  </div>
  <nav class="mobile-nav">
    <div class="hamburger-menu" id="hamburger-menu"></div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Testimonial</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```